# NGINX: CSS was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css"

Tags: css, nginx, mime

After searching and browsing a lot through different articles, I still don't have a solution for the following problem:

I get the Firefox error message:

> The stylesheet https://www.xxxxxx.at/assets/css/main.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/plain", is not "text/css".

​I'm running nginx:stable in Docker and use the following /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
 events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name XXXXXXXX;

        root /site_data/XXXXXXXX;
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / { }

        ssl_certificate /ssl/XXXXXXXX.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /ssl/XXXXXXXX.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout 1d;
        ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        # modern configuration
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    }
}
```

My website is basically:

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    ...
    </head>
    <body>...</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know a solution for this Firefox/Chrome problem?

Comment: Is your css somehow autogenerated? I had some cases where PHP generated my css and PHP had an error, and therefore the output was just an error message and not css. Thus, text/plain. Can you try to open the css file directly in your browser and confirm it's actual css in there?

Comment: It‘s valid CSS, can be opened in the browser directly. I also see that opening it directly, without using Nginx, also works just fine in the same browser.

Comment: *opening the whole site I mean

Comment: I don't get it. The issue is gone, without changing anything. Can this be a caching thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved, seems to be a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

cache problem
Ctrl+Shift+R to reload browser page might fix it.